# What is the RESTful endpoint to trigger a non-CRUD operation that doesn't alter the state?

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I have a `box` resource that has basic CRUD endpoints.
Now, I'm introducing a new operation to open the physical box that the `box` resource represents.

`box` resource doesn't have a state/attribute `isOpened` as it doesn't make sense in our case. The `box` representation doesn't care about the state of the physical box.

The new operation would contact the physical box and open it using its API.

What would endpoint would make the most sense for this operation?
I can open the box any times I want without any further action from the API.

Does `GET /boxes/1/open` make sense? Because it feels wrong to me for some reason.

Comment: I'd say a PUT or PATCH is good candidate for the described use case.

Answer (score 0):

> Does GET /boxes/1/open make sense?

Probably not.  `GET` says that the resource can be fetched speculatively.  Think about spiders crawling through your API and trying to `GET` every link to see what it does.

If we were doing this on the web, we would use `POST`, so that has to be OK.

`POST /boxes/1` could be the right answer.  If opening the box were to change the representation of the `/boxes/1` resource, then `POST /boxes/1` would make a lot of sense because the cache invalidation semantics.  But if the representation doesn't change, then you might prefer to send the request someplace completely different.

`POST /6a5cb697-81b8-4206-b1af-2d62254b7dc3` would be fine; but you might want a more human readable spelling.  You certainly could use `/boxes/1/open`; that could be useful because it is convenient to use relative references to reach other resources in the same part of the hierarchy.

`PUT` and `PATCH` are remote authoring tools; "make your representation of the resource match my representation of the resource".  Given the constraints you described, that means that `PUT /boxes/1` and `PATCH /boxes/1` are right out.  You could, in theory, create a new resource and PUT/PATCH its representation, but I don't think you get much advantage from doing that.

Some will complain that `/boxes/1/open` is "wrong" because open is a "verb".  As far as the machines are concerned, there's really no difference between

```
/boxes/1/open
/boxes/1/6a5cb697-81b8-4206-b1af-2d62254b7dc3
/boxes/1/bike-shed-paint-color
```